# Why is there no unit testing support in eclipse pdt?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, eclipse-pdt

Netbeans [has unit testing support](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html), in the upcoming 7.1 release they've even improved support to include [test group features](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/using_phpunit_test_groups), PDT, AFAIK, doesn't even have plans for unit testing support? Version 3.0 is available and not so much as a hint about unit testing support. Why? Is there something I'm missing?

## Update

I'm not really asking for a list of phpunit/unit-testing plugins for eclispe, a list can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966673/eclipse-pdt-phpunit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `eclipse-pti` based unit testing needs there is the [**`phpsrc.org`**](http://www.phpsrc.org/) plugin.

It supports the whole PHP QA-Stack.

---

I can't really tell you why there is no official support for phpunit in eclipse. I would assume it's because one doesn't need any plugin as it runs as an `external tool` ([**`sample video`**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7hTrig3rpw) ) but that just shows the console output.

Maybe anyone else has more insight into this. @hakre made some insightful comment regarding this on this answer.

Comment: Is that an official eclipse project that will eventually become part of the official pdt package? Or does eclipse recommend that package?

Comment: It is around for over 2 years and was nicely maintained and kept up to date quite nicely from what I can tell. But I don't know what qualifies as an "official pdt package". In case there is a list I don't know off I guess you can look that up. Same goes for recommended packages. If there is a list I don't know it.

Comment: +1 for PHPsrc, good tool, nice maintainer. You can swithch between the tests and code files with a button, get failed tests highlighted inside the source, test skeleton generation and that stuff. It's pretty well integrated into eclipse. Just ask questions here if you have problems to configure it ;)

Comment: @edorian Maybe, but I didn't really ask if there were any good unit testing plugins for pdt. Rather, why isn't unit testing part of the pdt package itself or even plans for it. Why not make PTI part of PDT, or at least recommend it as an officially recommended project? (given of course that there is no existing unit testing support in PDT itself)

Comment: Eclipse is a framework. PDT is a plugin like PTI is. It's just that it has a modular structure. Additionally PDT is driven by Zend and it's known that they don't want to have certain features in it to not let their own eclipse based editor look too poor: Zend Studio. So I think it's very good that PTI is not part of PDT. This keeps things more independent. An official list of Eclipse projects is available here if you're interested. It shows at well how Eclipse differs from Netbeans in it's structure (it's an application framework, not a IDE): http://www.eclipse.org/projects/listofprojects.php

Comment: There's a lot more to unit testing support than just running the tests, when I use eclipse I run them in the terminal but being able to switch between test and the class being tested via a keystroke e.g. Ctrl+Shift+T is really quite usefull

Comment: @hakre if PTI was an official eclipse project I'd be more than happy to use it and recommend it and publicise it. I understand Zend would be reluctant to add the kind of features that make their plugin look bad. How do you go about getting PTI into the official project or is it a case that Zend would not allow it? Or block it? Or make it difficult? Is the process of getting code into PDT broken? Is PTI good enough? And probably most important: is PTI willing to contribute the code into PDT?

Comment: Just use the [offical eclipse marketplace to locate PTI](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pti-php-tool-integration) and install it. Have fun ;). For more information about the Eclipse Foundation and it's structure, please visit http://eclipse.org/, the site provides all the information you've asked for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug for Eclipse that supports PHPUnit, SimpleTest and CakePHP. It is called MakeGood.

It works well here is a link.. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/1158